# SAM Template - Always enable event trigger for lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have a lambda function created using SAM template which has an event trigger scheduled every 5 mins.

When the lambda get created for first time the event is enabled. But, when someone disables the trigger manually, the rerunning the stack does not enable it again.

Native cloud formation has an attribute called `State` in [AWS::Events::Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html). But this is not supported in SAM Function's Events property. It is to be noted that this Events property gets translated to AWS::Events::Rule by SAM engine.

I tried adding the same State attribute in SAM but that doen't work.

Now the question is really how do I make sure Event is always enabled when SAM is used.

This there a hack available.

Sample code:

```
MyUpdater:
Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
Properties:
  Handler: myupdater.lambda_handler
  Runtime: python3.6
  FunctionName: "myupdater"
  CodeUri: ./code
  Description: Sample updater lambda
  MemorySize: 128
  Timeout: 60
  Role: !ImportValue myIamRole
  KmsKeyArn: !ImportValue myKeyArn
  Events:
    Timer:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
```

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today.  We are considering this feature (CFN properties pass-through) for the future.

Comment: You can not disable the trigger manually. Some resources created in some types of cloudformation stacks can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Add Enabled to properties:

```
Events:
    Timer:
      Type: Schedule
      Properties:
        Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
        Enabled: true
```